# zxing scan from website returns to new window

Tags: c#, jquery, mobile, barcode, zxing

This is most likely a browser issue, but I have a mobile website that I launch the zxing app from, passing in a callback URL.  Everything scans fine and returns the scanned data as I expect.

However, instead of the URL returning to the "**same**" `window/tab/etc` in the browser on the phone, a new window is opened with the URL.

Any thoughts on how to get it to return to the same window that launched the scanner?

BTW - This is a jquery mobile site build with `asp.net MVC 3`, and I'm using the default android  (4.0.4) browser.

Comment: have you solve your issue?  Also, how zxing return data to website? how I should handle it?

Comment: im not using zxing, but i have the same issue... callback url are opening new tab! u solved it?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to this was to create an android app that used the built in webclient.  When someone on the app clicked the scan button on the website, it would talk back to the app itself through javascript and launch the scanner.  The scanner had no idea it was called from the website.  It sent the data back to the app, which used javscript to pushed that back to the website.  This way, only one "tab" is ever open because it's how the app work.

Edit:  Of course that was almost 6 years ago, and I have no idea what all has changed since then.